# A right background color of a button with tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've stablished a background color in a button with Tkinter, but when I click into the button then the background color changes to the system color, in my case windows 8.1. Is there any way to fix that?
The code:

```
compute = tk.Button(rframe, text='Equals', command=comp_s, relief='flat', font=MY_FONT, background='blue', foreground='white')
compute.pack(side='left')
```

I'm using Python 3.4.2 64 bits

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While one holds down the left mouse button, the screen button changes to its 'active' colors.  The following works this way for me (Win7, 3.4.2).

```
from tkinter import *
r= Tk()
b= Button(text='hello', foreground='white', background='green',
          activeforeground='red', activebackground='blue')
b.pack()
```